# separable metric space undder continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove that continuous image of a separable metric space is separable.

Here's my attempt:
Assume $f:X\to Y$ is the continuous map from the separable metric space $X$ to metric space $Y$. Then there exists a countably dense subset $A$ of $X$.
I wanna prove $f(A)$ is a countably dense subset of $X$. It's obvious that $f(A)$ is countable since $A$ is countable. I need to show $\overline{f(A)}=f(X)$.
Since $f$ is continuous, $f(\overline{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$.
I have trouble in showing $\overline{f(A)}\subset f(\overline{A})=f(X)$.
Could someone help me? Thank in advanve

Comment: Lee, you should accept the answer or indicate what needs inprovement.

Answer (score 1):

Take an open set in $f(X)$, namely $V$. We need to show $V\cap f(A)$ in non empty. Because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ and by density there is a certain $a_n\in A$ such that $a_n\in f^{-1}( V)$. Hence, $f(a_n)\in V$ and $f(A)$ is dense as you suspected.

Feel free to enquire further if any step is not clear.